# How to reduce no of partition without changing in spark code

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, query-optimization

I have a code zip file executing through spark submit and it produce 200 output file now the question is without changing in as its a zip file
how to reduce no of output files?

Comment: why is that an issue?

Comment: @GauravKumar, If the answer helped you to resolve issue.. Could you **`upvote and accept`** the answer to close this thread! :-) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

If you are using config file and your code doing repartition by getting `number of partitions` from  **`config file`** dynamically then you can change the value in your config file, no need change zip file.

Another option would be using **`--conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=<number of partitions>`** in your `spark-submit` then your spark job will create number of files specified number.

**`NOTE:`** Setting up this param will **degrade** performance as this controls number of partitions whole spark program only advised to use if spark job is not processing millions of records.